# How to add a child theme or just a separate CSS file to Magento Theme or website

Tags: php, css, magento, content-management-system, magento2

Our website is build with Magento by external agency. I recently asked them to create a child theme for us or just a separate CSS file where I could do some changes without effecting the main theme.

They came back with quote of £65 * 8 hours work. I personally think creating a folder and dumping a css file wouldn't take 8 hours but I don't have Magento theme building experience so not sure how to reply back.

Could anyone help me, how to add a separate CSS file or child theme, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about the exact version of magento

Comment: yes it's Magento ver. 1.9.2.2